# Liferay Asset Publisher category ordering

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am using an Asset Publisher in Liferay DXP and grouping the displayed assets by a category vocabulary. I would like the categories to be displayed in a particular order but it seems to be alphabetic and the configuration doesn't provide any controls for this. I have a custom Asset Display Template but it controls the display of the assets within each category group, but the not the groups themselves. Can this be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The asset publisher offers an order and grouping configuration. Is it not working for you?

[image]